# Convert an unusual/custom time format to datetime object

Tags: python, timezone, datetime-format

I have an unusual datetime format in my dataset, which I need to convert to usable datetime object.

An example looks like: '1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)'

I have tried to parse it with:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)')
```

but it doesn't recognize the format.

My current workaround is to parse the datetime column (the data is in pandas dataframe) using regex into two columns, like so:

[image: dataframe]

and then depending on the value of the 'utc' column apply custom convert_to_eastern function.

**I wonder if there is an easier way to accomplish it using  datetime.datetime.strptime() ?**

Following didn't work:

```
import datetime as dt

my_time='1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)'
dt.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p(%z)')
```

Addition:
This is not a question: "How to convert UTC timezone into local timezone" My dataset has rows with UTC as well as Eastern time zone rows. The problem I have is that the format is not an ISO format, but some human-readable custom format.

Comment: i think your approach is write by converting `1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)` to `1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM+0` format and then using  dateutil.parser . but using panda data framework might slow your converting process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: an easier way to accomplish it using datetime.datetime.strptime()

Split the datestring into parts: `utc:[('1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM', '(UTC+0)', 'UTC', '+', '0')]`
Rebuild the datestring, fixing the `hour` part padding with `0` to 2 digits.
I assume, there are no `minutes` in the `UTC` part, therefore defaults to `00`.

If the datestring has more then 2 `UTC` digits, returns the unchanged datestring.

> **Note**: The `strptime` format have to be `%Z%z`!
>   Documentation: [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

def fix_UTC(s):
    utc = re.findall(r'(.+?)(\((\w{3})(\+|\-)(\d{1,2})\))', s)
    if utc:
        utc = utc[0]
        return '{}({}{}{})'.format(utc[0], utc[2], utc[3], '{:02}00'.format(int(utc[4])))
    else:
        return s

my_time = fix_UTC('1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)')
date = datetime.strptime(my_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p(%Z%z)')
print("{} {}".format(date, date.tzinfo))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 2018-01-03 13:29:35+01:00 UTC
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thanks, now I see the solution is to force the format to conform to ISO format, whether with regex or other string manipulation suggested above. Your regex+datetime.strptime() solution works and is a better alternative to my current work-around.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with '+0' for your timezone 'UTC+0'. [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) only takes utc offset in the form of `HHMM`. Possible workaround:

```
import datetime as dt

my_time = '1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0)'
my_time=my_time.replace('+0','+0000')
dt.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p(%Z%z)')
```

Comment: @prashantrana how do you know the format will be -5:30 and not -0530? This is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: it can be -0530 (ie %h%m notation ) or it can be %h:%m noation . in her dataset she mention that she has UTC and ETZ  time format plus in question it's given (utc+0) so i am assuming there might be different UTC value . while giving utc mostly %h:%m:%S%.%s format is used.

Comment: Exactly. Until she gives more information, we can only assume.

Comment: but using is .`.replace` function is totally wrong . she has already solve the problem with `dateutil.parser.parser` , by taking only +0  part from (utc+0). she just want a way to remove the regex part she done to take +0 portion.

Comment: Again, function is correct until she gives us more information. From the information given, the function works. Also, I said "Possible work around". And yes, I know she solved the problem with `parser` but the question is: "I wonder if there is an easier way to accomplish it using datetime.datetime.strptime() ? "

Comment: so this method only work when there is (utc+0) in time . else it's fail.

Comment: Yeup, and there is (utc+0) (in fact, it's the only one!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185375/discussion-between-ricky-kim-and-prashant-rana).

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that:

```
import datetime as dt

my_time='1/3/2018 1:29:35 PM(UTC+0000)'
tmp = dt.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p(%Z%z)')
print(tmp)
```

Big "Z" for timezone (UTC, GMT etc), small "z" for delta. Also you should add more zeros to delta.